# Lipschitz min implies Lipschitzian argmin?

Tags: convex-optimization, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis, set-valued-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, and suppose that $f:X^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz, supercoercive, convex function such that (for every $y \in X$) the set
$$
\operatorname*{argmin}_{x\in X} f(x,y),
$$
is single-valued and the map
$$
y \mapsto \min_{x\in X} f(x,y),
$$
is Lipschitz.

Is the map
$$
y\mapsto \operatorname*{argmin}_{x\in X} f(x,y)
,
$$
Lipschitz?
(If not what additional requirements are needed)?

Comment: Consider the case $X=\mathbb R$. If $g(x)$ is a conv x function with a very flat minimum at zero, then $f(x,y)=g(x)+xy$ has the property that the argmin is far from Lipschitz near $y=0$.

Comment: If the map is strictly convex then this should rule this out no?

Comment: I have in mind $g(x)=x^{2n}$ for example.

Comment: Hmm..then is there any easy condition on $f$?

Comment: This reminds me of proximal mappings: there you have $f(x,y) = g(x) +\|x-y\|_2^2$ and the argmin over x is always 1-Lipschitz in y.

Comment: Indeed, that's where the question stems from.  However, in this setting, it is less clear to me if things are Lipschitz.

Comment: Maybe you should add your definition of Lipschitz (maybe you mean "locally Lipschitz"?) and of supercoercive (is it $\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty}f(x)/\|x\|=+\infty$ what you mean?) because they are incompatible with each other in the common usage

Comment: And if it is convex, it is automatically locally Lipschitz (given that it is finite everywhere).